# There has been an error processing your request: "Module "CLS_VehicleFitmentIntegration" requires module "CLS_VehicleFitment"."

Tags: magento-1.9, module, error

I find this in the error log report after getting "There has been an error processing your request":

```
a:4:{i:0;s:76:"Module "CLS_VehicleFitmentIntegration" requires module "CLS_VehicleFitment".";i:1;s:751:"#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ac-fitment\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(849): Mage::throwException('Module "CLS_Veh...')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\ac-fitment\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(812): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_sortModuleDepends(Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\ac-fitment\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(315): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_loadDeclaredModules()
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\ac-fitment\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(425): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModules()
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\ac-fitment\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\ac-fitment\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\ac-fitment\index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#7 {main}";s:3:"url";s:21:"/ac-fitment/index.php";s:11:"script_name";s:21:"/ac-fitment/index.php";}
```

How can I resolve that?

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you what the problem is:

> Module "CLS_VehicleFitmentIntegration" requires module
>   "CLS_VehicleFitment"

Either the "CLS_VehicleFitment" module is not installed, or it is disabled under `app/etc/modules/CLS_VehicleFitment.xml`

Comment: This xml file have as  ../../../.modman/cls_vehiclefitment/app/etc/modules/CLS_VehicleFitment.xml

Comment: The patch you pasted is the modman file. Did you install using symlinks or hard copy ? Please check the original `app/etc/modules` folder and see what's there

Comment: hard copy. i have checked those, its contains <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <CLS_VehicleFitment>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Core/>
                <Mage_Catalog/>
                <Mage_CatalogSearch />
            </depends>
        </CLS_VehicleFitment>
    </modules>
</config>

Comment: Did you try flushing the cache ?

Comment: yes, i flushed the cache.